# Undefined references when using graphics.h?

Tags: c++, bgi

I am trying to use graphics.h in dev C++ 5.7.1.

I already searched the internet for the available options.
I downloaded the graphics.h library in the include folder and chose the following in the parameters option:

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

Still I cannot figure out why is it showing me these errors:

```
undefined reference to `initgraph'
undefined reference to `graphresult'
undefined reference to `grapherrormsg'
undefined reference to `getmaxx'
undefined reference to `getmaxy'
undefined reference to `getmaxcolor'
undefined reference to `getcolor'
undefined reference to `circle'
undefined reference to `closegraph'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status.
```

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<conio>
int main(void)
{
       /* request auto detection */
       int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
       int midx, midy;
       int radius = 100;
       /* initialize graphics and local variables */
       initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\include\\winbgim");
       /* read result of initialization */
       errorcode = graphresult();
       if (errorcode != grOk)  /* an error occurred */
       {
           printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
        printf("Press any key to halt:");
      getch();
      exit(1); /* terminate with an error code */
   }
   midx = getmaxx() / 2;
   midy = getmaxy() / 2;
   setcolor(getmaxcolor());
   /* draw the circle */
   circle(midx, midy, radius);
   /* clean up */
   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using [WinBGIm](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/).  Did you follow the installation instructions and put the libbgi.a file in your library directory?

Comment: Yes.I followed all the installation instructions properly.All the files are placed where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @AvniSingh Do you have a specific requirement to use `Dev-C++`? If not, I advise going for `SFML` instead as it provides ***far more*** functionality than `Dev-C++`. *Oh yes, and you can easily draw circles in it also.*

Answer (score 3):

Download following files to the directories mentioned:

*Here I assume you installed Dev-Cpp to* `C:\Dev-Cpp`

http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/graphics.h   Directory:> C:\Dev-Cpp\include
http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/libbgi.a  Directory:> C:\Dev-Cpp\lib

Create a new C++ project and set "Project Options->Parameters->Linker" as

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

and try executing this sample code; then go for the code that you posted above.

```
#include<graphics.h>

int main( ){
        initwindow( 700 , 700 , "MY First Program");
        circle(200, 200, 150);
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already tried the above mentioned.The files are in the mentioned directories.I tried running your code.It's still showing the same error:

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate that the function is not defined.  Functions are typically defined in the source code or a library (static or dynamic.)   Therefore, you need to either include the source code in your project so that it's linked along with your code above, or you will need to link to the precompiled library (perhaps an .a, .lib, or .dll file.)

I'm not overly familiar with the library you're using; however, I would assume that graphics.h includes the function declarations and does not include function definitions.

Comment: I checked the code for graphics.h.You were right.It includes only the function declarations and not the function definition.What would you suggest in order to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is linker error. Make sure library names you wrote in *Project Options->Parameters->Linker* start with "**-**".

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

as Zeke wrote above.